# How to remove these generated files from my file explorer?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a problem in my VSCode explorer.

After I build (filename).c files, some documentary files appear in my files explorer.

1. What is this documentary file?
2. How to avoid showing this documentary file?

Thanks for all your comment :)

[image]

Comment: Could you please translate the message text shown in the image?

Comment: Share your files under `/.vscode`, maybe some settings auto generate that.

Answer (score 0):

I think most probably that 'documentary' file will become a .exe file once you run your code. Don't worry about it. Write your code and run the code.I have something similar with my C++ files.Don't know about the hiding part though.[My file explorer also looks similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qytg2.png)

Comment: OP is using macOS, there are no `.exe` files. But your answer is otherwise correct: these are the compiled binaries.

Comment: ok. I have never used macOS , so was not aware.I guessed it was something similar to what i have in my system, Thanks.